# Excel VBA to INSERT data using SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I need some assistance in writing the following code. I wrote my comments where I am stuck:

```
Sub UploadDataUsingProc()

    Call CheckFields
    Call Variables.SetVariables
    Call Variables.VariableValues
    Dim sqlCommand As ADODB.Command
    Dim TargetServer As ADODB.Connection
    Set TargetServer = New ADODB.Connection
    TargetServer.CommandTimeout = 99999

    TargetServer.Open ( _
    "driver=" & driver & ";" & _
    "server=" & server & _
    ";database=" & databasename & ";" & _
    ";UID=" & username & _
    ";PWD=" & password & ";" & _
    "Encrypt=YES;")

    ' Set the stored procedure
    Set sqlCommand = New ADODB.Command
    sqlCommand.ActiveConnection = TargetServer
    sqlCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 'Set sqlCommand to be a stored procedure
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "Proc_ReportMonthlySubmission"

    ' This is where I am not sure how do code further... Following Excel fields needs to be
    ' inserted into a SQL Server table using a stored procedure called "Proc_ReportMonthlySubmission"
    '
    ' Worksheets("Keys").Range("D8").Value
    ' Worksheets("Keys").Range("D7").Value
    ' Worksheets("Keys").Range("D3").Value
    ' Worksheets("Keys").Range("D5").Value

    'Set Procedure = "Exec " & Procedure
    TargetServer.Execute (Procedure)
    MsgBox "Procedure has run"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267080/calling-stored-procedure-vba

Comment: @TimWilliams - I  appreciate your example and I reviewed it but where do I enter the spreadsheet cell numbers within the code?  So it can pass those values through the store procedure... Following are the cell numbers where I need to get the values and pass them to the Procedure:

Comment: @TimWilliams    ' Worksheets("Keys").Range("D8").Value
    ' Worksheets("Keys").Range("D7").Value
    ' Worksheets("Keys").Range("D3").Value
    ' Worksheets("Keys").Range("D5").Value

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26230428/vba-call-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-two-arguments - the answers there show how the values are assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one... (just follow [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26230428/vba-call-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-two-arguments), as exposed by Tim Williams)

```
With sqlCommand
    .Parameters.Item("Whatever_field_you_have").Value = _
                              Worksheets("Keys").Range("D8").Value
    ...
```

End With

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)